# Continuous Failing to pull Docker Image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, amazon-eks, docker-image

I'm getting this issue all the time when I try pulling image to my EKS cluster, it says pull rate limit is reached, but when I try pulling it to my local computer it works.

```
 Failed to pull image "myrepo/postgres:12-alpine": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading:
```

All the images are public,

Can someone guide me through this issue since still I cannot get it deployed in my kube cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the limits are per IP. So, your local machine ip still have "free" pulls. The problem is that (most probably) the IP of your cluster is "shared" between multiple (virtual) machines, so they are all limited per 100 pulls/6h.
You can increase your limit by authenticating, see https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limits

Read more about rate limits here https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/download-rate-limit/

Comment: Is that basically for any pull for docker hub or is it specific for my repo in docker hub ?

Comment: it is default for all free repositories. There are only a few exceptions.